# consume queue from multiple vhosts with kombu

Tags: rabbitmq, producer-consumer, kombu

I have the following situation. I have a list of vhosts. In each vhost i have a queue (same name in all vhosts). Is there a way to simultaneously consume the queues? (i don't want to create a separate process for each vhost) I want to have a single consumer, consuming from all the queues.
I'm using kombu and rabbitmq.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html:

> amqp_URI       = "amqp://" amqp_authority [ "/" vhost ] [ "?" query ]
>
> amqp_authority = [ amqp_userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]
>
> amqp_userinfo  = username [ ":" password ]
>
> username       = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims )
>
> password       = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims )
>
> vhost          = segment

You need one connection for each `vhost`.
So, no you can't.

And in general you can't have a single subscriber for multiple queues, even if they are in the same `vhost`